# Select N values from an array based on probabilities - Pyspark

Tags: python, arrays, random, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to sample 3 items from an array of 4 items based on the probability of the items occurring. The input is an array of items and there is another array with the probability of the item being selected:

I tried creating a udf and passing the array values to it, with some modification I got that to work but it picks up items with replacement, I want the items to be unique in the sample.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, ['A','B','C','D'], [0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]), 
     (2, ['X','Y','Z','Q'], [0.8,0.1,0.1,0.0]),
     (3, ['Z','P','Q','R'], [0.6,0.3,0.1,0.1]),
     (4, ['P','M','R','Q'], [0.7,0.2,0.1,0.0]),
     (5, ['P','M','R','Q'], [0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1])], 
    ["id", "item_id", "probability"])

import random
def wt_sample(item, wt):
    return(random.choices(item, weights=wt, k=3))

udf_wt_sample = F.udf(wt_sample, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
df.withColumn("sample", udf_wt_sample(col("items"), col("probability"))).show()
```

Tried `np.random.choice` which lets me specify if I want replacement but this takes too long and errors out:

```
import numpy as np
def wt_sample(item, wt):
    return np.random.choice(item,size=3,replace=False, p=wt)

udf_wt_sample = F.udf(wt_sample, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
```

Input:

```
+--+-----------+-----------------+
|id|    item_id|      probability|
+--------------+-----------------+
| 1|  [A,B,C,D]|[0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]|
| 2|  [X,Y,Z,Q]|[0.8,0.1,0.1,0.0]|
| 3|  [Z,P,Q,R]|[0.6,0.3,0.1,0.1]|
| 4|  [P,M,R,Q]|[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.0]|
| 5|  [P,M,R,Q]|[0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]|
+--------------+-----------------+
```

The output should look like this:

```
+--+-----------+-----------------+-------+
|id|    item_id|      probability| sample|
+--------------+-----------------+-------+
| 1|  [A,B,C,D]|[0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]|[A,B,D]|
| 2|  [X,Y,Z,Q]|[0.8,0.1,0.1,0.0]|[X,Z,Q]|
| 3|  [Z,P,Q,R]|[0.6,0.3,0.1,0.1]|[Z,P,M]|
| 4|  [P,M,R,Q]|[0.7,0.2,0.1,0.0]|[P,M,R]|
| 5|  [P,M,R,Q]|[0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]|[M,R,Q]|
+--------------+-----------------+-------+
```

I did find a UDF that works: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549515/weighted-random-sample-without-replacement-in-python), but it has scalability issues with a lot of data:

```
def wt_sample(items, wts, k=3):
    wts = list(wts)
    positions = range(len(items))
    indices = []
    while True:
        needed = k - len(indices)
        if not needed:
            break
        for i in random.choices(positions, wts, k=needed):
            if wts[i]:
                wts[i] = 0.0
                indices.append(i)
    return [items[i] for i in indices]
```

It takes too long with a really high-power machine to run this code. So would like an optimized solution.

The samples should be selected based on the probability randomly and shouldn't just be the top-3 values. That's why I tried to use the `random.choices()` fn with weights but I need the sample values to be unique without replacement (Currently the output is with replacement when I use `random.choices()`, so the same item can be picked twice in the sample).

Comment: How do you intend to use the probability column? doe this work? `df.withColumn("items",F.slice(F.shuffle("item_id"),1,3)).show()` or `df.withColumn("items",F.expr("slice(shuffle(item_id),1,3)"))`

Comment: If above works, this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176320/random-sample-from-column-of-arraytype-pyspark

Comment: Yeah, I saw that answer but I need to select the 3 samples from item_id based on the probability column and not just randomly sample from the item_id array. I need a weighted sample that is based on the probability array.